# Python CSV different delimiter

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read a file that has **`** as delimiters. I have tried some of the other solutions for a different delimiter but none seemed to work.

```
with open("data.csv", "r") as data:
    for line in data:
        for line.split('`') as element:
            print(element)
```

example input file:

```
sarah`120`18kg`22Rep
thomas`160`8kg`11Rep
```

the expected out should be:

```
sarah
120
18kg
22Rep
thomas
160
8kg
11Rep
```

but this is what I get:

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why not use the CSV library that is built into Python? https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using the DictReader class from the standard library like so:

```py
import csv

def read_csv(filepath: str) -> list:
    """Read csv file from given path, return contents as list of dictionaries"""
    with open(filepath, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        r = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='`')
        return list(r)

print(read_csv("data.csv"))
```

Comment: it worked thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a python csv library called pandas.

I found a [tutorial](https://thispointer.com/pandas-read-csv-file-to-dataframe-with-custom-delimiter-in-python/) that shows you how to use custom delimiters.

```py
pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep=', ', delimiter=None, header='infer', names=None, index_col=None, ....)
```

I think this line will be most useful to you.

Comment: You can also read CSV's natively without a 3rd party library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to test this but your loop on all of the elements looks incorrect. Try:

```
with open("data.csv", "r") as data:
    for line in data:
        for element in line.split('`'):
            print(element)
```